# PowerShell 6 doesn't find Excel Interop. PowerShell 5.1 does

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-office

In order to use constants from the xlFileFormat enum, I used

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel")
```

In the PowerShell 5.1 it works. Now I do transition to PowerShell 6. The same line issues the error message:

> Exception calling "LoadWithPartialName" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Operation is not supported."

Calling Add-Type instead, I get an error too:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
```

> Add-Type : Cannot find path 'C:\transform\software\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' because it does not exist.

How can I load the Interop DLL installed with the Office?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ***Windows PowerShell***, which is built on (the full) .NET Framework, loading assemblies with `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName()` or - preferably - `Add-Type -AssemblyName` **looks for assemblies in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache)**, and seemingly in *both*:

- the **.NET Framework 4+ GAC**, `$env:WINDIR\Microsoft.Net\assembly`
- ***and also*** the older **.NET Framework 3.x- GAC**, `$env:WINDIR\assembly`

**`Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel.dll` is located in the .NET Framework 3.x- GAC (only)**, so Windows PowerShell is able to find it by the assembly's *simple name* (partial name), `Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel`.

---

***PowerShell [Core]* is built on .NET Core, which itself has no GAC**.

In PowerShell [Core], `Add-Type -AssemblyName`:

- first looks in the **current directory**,
- then **among the assemblies in `$PSHOME`**, PowerShell Core's installation folder.
- and, finally, in the **.NET Framework 4+ GAC**, but seemingly ***not*** the **.NET Framework 3.x- GAC** (as tested in .NET Core 3.1 / PowerShell [Core] 7.0, with the exception noted below) - *presumably*, because the assemblies there are *assumed* to be incompatible with .NET Core - even though not all of them technically are.

Therefore,

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel')
```

*doesn't* find the assembly.

Curiously, `Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel` *finds* it<sup>[1]</sup>, but *fails to load the actual types*, which you can see by adding `-PassThru`.

---

Generally, speaking:

- You can **load assemblies by (full) *file path*** with `Add-Type -LiteralPath`.

  - Note that `Add-Type` not reporting an error is itself *not* enough to conclude that its types are *usable*:
    adding `-PassThru` is a quick way to verify that: normally, information about the types should be listed; otherwise, you'll see errors.
    <sup>Note that assemblies may be stub assemblies that themselves contain no types and instead forward types from different assemblies; as of PowerShell 7.0, `-PassThru` then produces no output rather than listing the forwarded types - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10802).</sup>
- If you **place an assembly, say `Foo.Bar.dll`, in your script's folder,** you can load it with
  `Add-Type -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot/Foo.Bar.dll`

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell [Core] seems to have its own logic for locating assemblies in the GAC: see method `TryFindInGAC` in [`CorePsAssemblyLoadContext.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/CoreCLR/CorePsAssemblyLoadContext.cs). However, the .NET 3.x- GAC, `$env:WINDIR\assembly`, appears *not* to be searched, so I have no explanation for why `Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Excel` is found  - which is not also present in the .NET 4+ GAC - is found; any other .NET 3.x- GAC-only assemblies appear not to be found as expected.</sup>

Comment: Thank you!

I succeed with `Add-Type -AssemblyName` having been copied the DLL from `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\(my_version)` to the script's directory.

I don't like this method because of manual work, that depends on my particular interop version's directory path, and need to cd into my script's directory before calling `Add-Type -AssemblyName`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a little more flexible way to access it from PowerShell 7:

```
$original_pwd = (Get-Location).Path

cd  C:\Windows\assembly\

$interop_assemply_location = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll).Directory

cd $interop_assemply_location 

Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" 

cd "$original_pwd"

$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application

$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
```

Comment: if you want it to be more flexible then you need to use `cd "$env:windir\assembly"` instead of hard-coding the path

Answer (score 1):

Based on Adrian's code and Phuclv's comment:

```
$AssemblyFile = (get-childitem $env:windir\assembly -Recurse Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll | Select-Object -first 1).FullName
Add-Type -Path $AssemblyFile
```